# Radio Button CSS Styling

Tags: css

Can anyone please help with some CSS. I have the following which works perfectly in some browsers like Firefox. But doesn't when in Chrome or IE. Can some help point me in the right direction please?

I have tried a few different things but not getting much luck.

I am trying to show a colour block then clients can click on to change the colour of the background. I can do this with standard radio buttons, but trying to make it more user friendly.

```
.colour-select table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.colour-select td:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.colour-select input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
}

.colour-select input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)   input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked:after,
.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6) input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #01f9ea;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #5e5f5f;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #3ea648;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #1b4621;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #cf242a;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #751112;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #f89520;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #fcee27;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #f2d48e;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #8c6330;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #2a327e;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #b2c9d5;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #3f87c7;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #812990;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #f06ea9;
}

.colour-select tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #f7b5d2;
}


.custom-colour tr:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.colour-picker-button {
  border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  margin: 10px 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colour-picker-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.colour-picker-preview {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: `input` elements do not have child elements, therefor `:before`/`:after` - which are essentially inserting new child elements - are not supposed to work on them in the first place. And apart from that, without the `content` property set to a different value than the default `none`, they would not insert anything anywhere to begin with. Plus, to make this an actually answerable question, please also show your HTML code. Go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve] example.